# Pubnub history seems incomplete

Tags: pubnub

Why does the following only log `100`?

```
count = 999;
pubnub.history({
    channel : chnl,
    callback : function(m){
        var msgs = m[0];
        console.log(msgs.length);
    },
    count : count
});
```

I manually set the count to 200 and I still only get 100 results.  I **know** I have more data than that.  As a matter of fact, I can push another message now, refresh the page and it will still only be 100.  Why does it only return/process 100?

Comment: If I set the count to 25 it returns 25, so I think my syntax is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on maximum number of messages which can be returned with single API call and it is 100 messages.

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: So I'll have to implement some sort of "paging" to get more than that?  That is... unfortunate.

Comment: Scott - we are in design with a new Storage architecture and History API that will have many more features and much easier to use. We know you will like what we roll out (no roadmap/timeline to share at this time though).